# Use of background field method

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization

How do we use the [background field method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_field_method) for renormalize a gauge theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background field method is a technique to calculate the effective action of a gauge theory by expanding a quantum field around a classical (background) value. This approach preserves the gauge invariance of the theory and simplifies the calculation of radiative corrections.

To renormalize a gauge theory using the background field method, one has to perform the following steps:

Choose a gauge-fixing condition and introduce ghost fields to maintain unitarity.

Split the quantum fields into background and fluctuation fields and write the action in terms of them.$

Introduce a regularization scheme such as dimensional regularization to regulate the divergences.

Calculate the one-loop effective action by integrating out the fluctuation fields and ghost fields.

Identify the divergent terms in the effective action and add counterterms that cancel them.

Use the Ward identities or BRST symmetry to determine the relations among the counterterms and ensure gauge invariance.

Renormalize the physical parameters of the theory by absorbing the finite parts of the counterterms into them.